# Test if user has application installed with Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

What is the most current method to determine if a Facebook User has installed an application? I see that there is an "installed" field on the "permissions" connection of a user object, but that requires an access_token to test. What happened to isAppUser and why does [this URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.isAppUser/) say the following:

> Please use the Graph API User object and GET /[UID]?field=installed to
>   check if a user is has TOSed that app.

The referenced /[UID]?field=installed does nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is working for me when asking for 'fields' - the docs appear to be referencing 'field' which I think is incorrect, I'll get it updated if that's the case:

e.g.

GET `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=installed&access_token=<SNIPPED TOKEN>`

Returns:

```
{
   "installed": true,
   "id": "<SNIPPED ID>"
}
```

A call to `/me/permissions` is probably what you want in most cases as this will also show the extended permissions granted to your app

Comment: Update: this was a typo in the docs, i've updated it now.
The correct parameter to retrieve specific of non-default fields (such as installed) is `fields`, not `field`

Comment: What if we want to know if the user has installed an app belonging to someone else?

Comment: I don't believe that information is available, and I can't think of a good reason for it to be available either